# What is Petyr Baelish planning with regards to Arya?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In season 7 episode 5 we see Arya spying on Baelish. Apparently, Petyr is aware of this and plants a hidden scroll in his room for Arya to find. What did the scroll say, and what is Petyr trying to do?

Comment: This is **entirely** speculative and therefore opinion-based and so **off-topic**

Comment: Agreed. We're in territory the books haven't gotten to yet, so no one knows what's being planned at this point. Really the only "right" answer is, "Watch the show and find out."

Comment: We know he's planning *something*, the showrunners have said so but what it **actually** is, is entirely speculative as the answer below indicates. These are all *theories*...not stated facts.

Comment: VTRO: This has an answer from one of the show's creators.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think this is **entirely** speculative because one of the questions is "What did the scroll say?" which can be answered objectively since the scroll was shown on screen.

Comment: @Ovi Then it's multiple questions and too broad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[One theory popular on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/6tjjj8/spoilers_extended_the_letter/dll7ohz/) is that Petyr has swapped the letter. What he requested from Measter Wolkan was the letter Lysa wrote to Catelyn falsely claiming that the Lannisters murdered Jon Arryn. In "Mockingbird" (S04E07) Lysa essentially confessed to Sansa:

> Liar! Whore! He is mine! My father, my husband, my sister, they all stood between us and now they're all dead. That's what happens to people who stand between Petyr and me.

This letter would further implicate Petyr in starting the War of the Five Kings which cost the Starks so dearly.

But the theory suggests he swapped it for the letter we see on screen, one Sansa wrote to Robb:

> Robb, I write to you with a heavy heart. Our good king Robert is dead, killed from wounds he took in a boar hunt. Father has been charged with treason. He conspired with Robert’s brothers against my beloved Joffrey and tried to steal his throne. The Lannisters are treating me very well and provide me with every comfort. I beg you: come to King’s Landing, swear fealty to King Joffrey and prevent any strife between the great houses of Lannister and Stark.

Such a letter does not hurt Petyr at all, but could drive a wedge between Sansa and Arya. In addition to making it seem as though Sansa had betrayed her family, it is significant that Sansa forgot to mention Arya, a [fact noted twice in the books](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/6tjjj8/spoilers_extended_the_letter/dll6zbo/). Had she mentioned that Arya was missing, it would have shown that she did have concern for her sister, as well as showing the Lannister's duplicitous character when they attempted to trade Jaime for the two Stark girls when they only had Sansa.

Comment: I did see Jeoffrey's name on that note, and my son who was watching with me immediately said "he planted it to turn them against each other."  Of course, he clearly doesn't entirely understand the whole Bran-factor yet....

Comment: You don't need reddit when there is show runner quotes to prove what you say is true.